# Quaternion or 3x3 Rotation Matrix Solver

Tags: matrices, rotations, quaternions

Is there a generalized formula or formulas be it that quaternion multiplication is not commutative, to solve for the equations:

Qa * X = Qb; solve for X

X * Qa = Qb; solve for X

where Qa is an arbitrary quaternion with Qb as a target quaternion?

Be it that quaternion multiplication and rotation matrix multiplication are supposed to be isomorphic as I've read, is there an equivalent equation for 3x3 rotation matrices?

Comment: Quaternion multiplication is not commutative but it has inverses. If $q_ax=q_b$ then $x=q_a^{-1}q_b$.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. What about in the secondary case with x*Q_a=Q_b?

Comment: I'll give you one guess.

Comment: In the other case when I'm trying on a quaternion calculator (http://bluetulip.org/2014/programs/quaternions.html) it seems like Q_a * Q_b^-1 = X^-1, is that correct?

Comment: If you'll write up in the answers I'll give the credit.

Comment: or well Q_a*Q_b^-1=X in that case, which seems to be the inverse of the X in the first problem.

Comment: No, if you have $xq_a=q_b$, you right-multiply both sides by the inverse of $q_a$ to get $xq_aq_a^{-1}=q_bq_a^{-1}$, so $x=q_bq_a^{-1}$. (Your earlier comment $x^{-1}=q_aq_b^{-1}$ is also correct, since $(q_bq_a^{-1})^{-1}=q_aq_b^{-1}$.)